# Peierl Inequality for infinite-dim Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a separable complex Hilbert space and $A$ be a self-adjoint bounded operator on $\mathscr{H}$. Let $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be convex. Then is it true that
$$
\operatorname{tr}{h(A)}=\sup \sum_n h(\langle x_n|A x_n\rangle)
$$
where the supremum is taken over othonormal-families $x_n$.

This is trivial for finite-dim $\mathscr{H}$, but what about infinite-dim? I would hope that this is true regardless of $\operatorname{tr}{h(A)} =\infty$ or $<\infty$. However, I would be glad with just proving that this is true if $h(A)$ is in trace-class.

On another note, are there any good references that deal with infinite-dim [trace inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Peierls%E2%80%93Bogoliubov_inequality)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $h$ is continuous. By functional calculus (or the Spectral Theorem), the operator $B=h(A)$ is positive. We have
$$\tag1
\operatorname{tr}(B)=\sum_n\langle x_n,Bx_n\rangle
$$
for any orthonormal basis $\{x_n\}$. Now if $\{y_n\}$ is an orthonormal set, choose $\{z_n\}$ such that $\{y_n\}\cup\{z_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Then, since $\langle x,Bx\rangle\geq0$ for all $x$,
$$\tag2
\sum_n\langle y_n,By_n\rangle\leq \sum_n\langle y_n,By_n\rangle+\sum_n\langle z_n,Bz_n\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(B). 
$$

Comment: Yes, but what about the other way around. I feel like that is the more difficult inequality.

Comment: What "other way around"?

Comment: I think you only prove $\operatorname{tr}{h(A)} \ge\sup \sum_n \langle x_n|h(A)x_n\rangle$, but what about $\le$.

Comment: $(2)$ shows that $\operatorname{tr}(B)$ is an upper bound. $(1)$ shows that it belongs to the set. So it is the least upper bound.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was my mistake. I edited my question.